# GWT query from client java side

Tags: java, gwt, client-side, google-visualization

Im trying to query a set of data from the server. The response should result in a DataTable instance that can be directly used to render a Google Visualization Widget (PieChart or whatever).

My Problem is, that the official tutorials only include javascript code for generating such a query..

I found out, that the following should work:

```
        Query q = Query.create(url);
    q.send(new Query.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(QueryResponse queryResponse) {
            if (!queryResponse.isError()) {
                DataTable table = queryResponse.getDataTable();
            }

        }
    });
```

But to use this you'll have to fill the url String variable. Of course you can just write it, but thats really disgusting if you change the mapping of your servlet to something else, you'll have to touch every query...
Is there a simple way to generate these urls to do such query calls?

Thx

Jonas

Comment: You could externalize the string in a single place for your whole application, and then reference that instead of typing the url in each place.

Comment: I'll stick with this solution. Seems the most intelligent at the moment... If I get enlighted somehow I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

GWT offers specialized framework [GWT-RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) for client-server interactions. It's 100% Java, its server implementation is based on servlets, and it takes care of low-level details such as server urls, object serializations, etc.

Also, you may find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156563/what-do-you-use-for-client-to-server-communication-with-gwt) relevant.

Comment: I know RPC.. RPC is absolutely awesome but doesn't serve datasource requests.. At least as far as I know :)

Comment: Then it's no different from doing this in straight JS Google Visualization. And, yes, gwt lets you externalize or retrieve url from the server, depending on your needs.